# Navigation drawer menu wont open activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

What i have is left navigation menu which i have made it using navigation drawer , it was working just fine with fragments but when i tried to change it to work with activities , **it show me a black screen with no errors in the logcat** , here is my code :

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Activity activity=null;
//on create and other things
//.
//.
//.
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        //android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            activity = new MainActivity();

            break;
        case 1:
            //fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
            break;
        case 2:
            //fragment = new PhotosFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            //fragment = new CommunityFragment();
            break;
        case 4:
            //fragment = new PagesFragment();
            break;
        case 5:
            //fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        if(activity != null) {
             Intent i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity.getClass());
             i1.putExtra("case 0", position);
             startActivity(i1);  
             setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
             mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
          }

        else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }
```

Can anyone tell what is the problem??

Comment: I feel that creating a new activity object is not really what you want to do.  I would remove the `activity = new MainActivity()` and move the intent creation and `startActivity()` into the case statement.  Make sure that you can start the activity normally by replacing `activity.getClass()` with `MainActivity.class`.

Comment: i did this before but it didn't work

Comment: I've only ever created Activities with `Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)`.  Can you post the code you tried before?

Comment: Intent i1= new Intent();
  switch (position) {
  case 0:
        i1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
       startActivity(i1); 
   break;

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to start up the main activity again, but I would try adding a `finish()` after the `startActivity(intent)`.  Take a look at the Activity stack documentation to make sure you don't need to add any flags upon startup.  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: because this menu exist in the main activity but the other menu will be in other activities.. got it?

Comment: Not quite.  The navigation drawer will only be accessed in the context of the MainActivity.  My next questionis:  When the MainActivity is created from the drawer, do you want the original MainActivity to be opened or finished?  I'm just trying to get a picture in my head what you're trying to accomplish in terms of flow.

Comment: i want it to be opened .. and this menu exist on all of the activities so sure some where i will have it in the main activity and the button of the main activity in the menu open the main activity everywhere .. got it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is weird:

```
new MainActivity();
```

You shouldn't make `Activity` objects by yourself, this should be done by `ActivityManager`. I would do the following:

```
Intent startIntent;
...
case 0:
        startIntent =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
        startIntent.putExtra("case 0", position);
        break;
...
if(intent != null) {
    startActivity(startIntent);  
}
```

By the way, per your code you are trying to start the same, already running `MainActivity`.

Comment: ok i have tried your code .. and i put another activity the weird thing that the seconed activity opens by it self without clicking the button .. why this is happening?

Comment: This is because 'case 0:' gets called automatically upon creating the drawer.  In your onCreate() method call `displayView(default_position)` after you setup the navigation drawer, where `default_position` is the case you would like called on startup.

Answer (score 0):

Check Below Code

```
 Intent i1; 

 private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    //android.app.Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        i1 =  new Intent(MainActivity.this, activity.Class);
        i1.putExtra("case 0", position);
        break;
    case 1:
        //fragment = new FindPeopleFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        //fragment = new PhotosFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        //fragment = new CommunityFragment();
        break;
    case 4:
        //fragment = new PagesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        //fragment = new WhatsHotFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
    if(activity != null) {
         mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
         startActivity(i1);  


      }

    else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```